# get image collections from certain html dom elements only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

```
document.images
```

can get image collections from `index` or `id` only.

But I need to get image collections from a certain table column only.

```
var m_images = aData[2];
```

This variable holds the content of a column in a table whose html looks like this:

```
<a href="" target="_blank"><img src="abc.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="" target="_blank"><img src="xyz.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

How can I get image collections from this particular variable only?

E.g. `m_images[0] = <img src="abc.com">, m_images[1] = <img src="xyz.com">`

I tried doing this (silly) `m_images.images` but got `undefined` which is obvious.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you add more info?

Comment: `$("table img")` will return all the image tags inside the table. is that what you want?

Comment: With [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you should be able to filter out which elements you want. For example `querySelectorAll('table img')` gives you all images inside a table.

Comment: "a table whose html looks like this" - that is not a table that you have posted there.

Comment: `document.getElementById('mytableid').getElementsByTagName('img')` or `document.getElementById('mytableid').getElementsByTagName('td').getElementsByTagName('img')`  You might also look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces#Manipulating_the_table_with_DOM_and_CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images using `querySelectorAll` like below

```js
var selector = 'img';
// you can change the selector based on your need
images = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
images.forEach(function(item, index){
    console.log("item", item)
    console.log("src", item.src)
});
```

Comment: "from a certain table column only" does not appear to be addressed here

Answer (score -1):

Just get the rows and walk them for the column index where they have an image.
Note, the question was unclear so I assumed multiple images possible in one `td` cell.

```js
let myColumnIndex = 2;
let myrows = document.getElementById('mytableid')
  .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("tr");
//console.log(myrows);
let myimages = [];
for (let row = 0; row < myrows.length; row++) {
  let tdimage = myrows[row]
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[myColumnIndex]
    .getElementsByTagName("img");
   console.log(tdimage);
   if (!!tdimage.length) {
   Array.prototype.forEach.call (tdimage, function (image) {
      console.log(image);
      myimages.push(image);
    });
  }
}
console.log(myimages);
```

```html
<table id="mytableid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Image:</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="abc.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Image:</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="xyz.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Image:</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="xyz3.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="try3.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```